# How to change default comment color in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
Tool/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors
```

I have problems to find which color display item I should change in order to change the default color for triple slash comments:

```
/// code here
```

Now, I am able to change color display item for the standard single line comments like

```
// code here.
```

Any tips?

Thank you

Comment: why should I put code? My question is asking for how to change color for displaying the commented code.

Answer (score 20):

Finally, I found the solution as follows:

Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors/XML Doc Comments

Answer (score 5):

There are several comments types that you can change, I just ran through all of my settings and outputting what matched my styles so it may be overkill, but it is the exhaustive list. I like all of my comments to appear the same so I change them all at once.

- Comment
- CSS Comment
- HTML Comment
- VB Xml Comment
- VB XML Doc Comment
- VB Xml Doc Tag
- VB Script Comment
- XAML Comment
- XML Comment
- XML Doc Comment
- XML Doc Tag

Answer (score 4):

In the `Fonts and Colors` menu you mentioned, you want to change the `XML Doc Tag` display item. You can change the other XML properties there to further customize the attributes within the triple slash comment.